# Calculating when multiple writes to a file will cause inaccuracies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

in my node server I have a variable,

```
var clicks = 0;
```

each time a user clicks in the webapp, a websocket event sends a message. on the server,

```
clicks++;
if (clicks % 10 == 0) {
  saveClicks();
}

function saveClicks() {
    var placementData = JSON.stringify({'clicks' : clicks});
    fs.writeFile( __dirname + '/clicks.json', placementData, function(err) {
    });
}
```

At what rate do I have to start worrying about overwrites? How would I calculate this math?

(I'm looking at creating a MongoDB json object for each click but I'm curious what a native solution can offer).

Comment: From the node.js doc: ***Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile()` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, `fs.createWriteStream()` is strongly recommended.***  This isn't a math problem to figure out when this might cause a problem - it's just bad code that gives you the chance of a conflict.  Write the code in a way that a conflict cannot happen.

Comment: @jfriend00 That should be the answer rather than just a comment

Comment: @AlexMcMillan - I wrote an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the node.js doc for `fs.writeFile()`:

> Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile()` multiple times on the
>   same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario,
>   `fs.createWriteStream()` is strongly recommended.

This isn't a math problem to figure out when this might cause a problem - it's just bad code that gives you the chance of a conflict in circumstances that cannot be predicted. The node.js doc clearly states that this can cause a conflict.

To make sure you don't have a conflict, write the code in a different way so a conflict cannot happen.

If you want to make sure that all writes happen in the proper order of incoming requests so the last request to arrive is always the one who ends up in the file, then you make need to queue your data as it arrives (so order is preserved) and write to the file in a way that opens the file for exclusive access so no other request can write while that prior request is still writing and handle contention errors appropriately.

This is an issue that databases mostly do for you automatically so it may be one reason to use a database.

Assuming you weren't using clustering and thus do not have multiple processes trying to write to this file and that you just want to make sure the last value sent is the one written to the file by this process, you could do something like this:

```
var saveClicks = (function() {
    var isWriting = false;
    var lastData;
    return function() {
        // always save most recent data here
        lastData = JSON.stringify({'clicks' : clicks});
        if (!isWriting) {
            writeData(lastData);
        }

        function writeData(data) {
            isWriting = true;
            lastData = null;
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/clicks.json', data, function(err) {
                isWriting = false;
                if (err) {
                    // decide what to do if an error occurs
                }
                // if more data arrived while we were writing this, then write it now
                if (lastData) {
                    writeData(lastData);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

@jfriend00 is definitely right about `createWriteStream` and already made a point about the database, and everything's pretty much said, but I would like to emphasize on the point about databases because basically the file-saving approach seems weird to me.

### So, use databases.

Not only would this save you from the headache of tracking such things, but would significantly speed up things (remember that the way stuff is done in node, the numerous file reading-writing processes would be parallelized in a single thread, so basically if one of them lasts for ages, it might slightly affect the overall performance).

[Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) is a perfect solution to store key-value data, so you can store data like clicks per user in a Redis database which you'll have to get running alongside anyway when your get enough traffic :)

If you're not convinced yet, take a look at this simple benchmark:

#### Redis:

```
var async = require('async');
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

console.time("To Redis");
async.mapLimit(new Array(100000).fill(0), 1, (el, cb) => client.set("./test", 777, cb), () => {
    console.timeEnd("To Redis");
});
```

> To Redis: 5410.383ms

#### fs:

```
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');

console.time("To file");
async.mapLimit(new Array(100000).fill(0), 1, (el, cb) => fs.writeFile("./test", 777, cb), () => {
    console.timeEnd("To file");
});
```

> To file: 20344.749ms

And, by the way, you can significantly increase the number of clicks after which the progress would be stored (now it's 10) by simply adding this "click-saver" to the socket `socket.on('disconnect', ...`.

Comment: I assumed that the OP is trying to write to a file because they want the data persisted to disk that will survive a process shutdown.  `redis`, while a very useful tool, is an in-memory store.  If they just want the data in-memory, they can just leave it in the `clicks` data structure they already have or copy it to some other JS array.  Also, since redis is in-memory, it is expected that it would be faster than writing to disk.

Comment: Thank you! I was just trying to make a simple app. I'm going with Mongo as I do want persisted database.